# Start counter on the scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, counter

I use two function on JQuery.

The first one is a counter [(View here)](https://jsfiddle.net/a52e24Ls/) and the second for start the counter when the Div is center on the window.

**Counter**

JS :

```
$('.counter').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this),
      countTo = $this.attr('data-count');

    $({
      countNum: $this.text()
    }).animate({
        countNum: countTo
      },

      {

        duration: 3000,
        easing: 'linear',
        step: function() {
          $this.text(Math.floor(this.countNum));
        },
        complete: function() {
          $this.text(this.countNum);
        }

      });

});
```

HTML :

```
<div class="counter" data-count="10000">0</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/a52e24Ls/

*

*

**Scroll detection**

JS :

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
      startCounter();
    });

$(window).load(function(){
      startCounter();
    });

function startCounter(){

      $('.contributorTitle').each(function(i) {

        var bottom_of_object = $(this).position().top + ($(this).outerHeight()/2);
        var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();

        if (bottom_of_object < bottom_of_window){

        }

      });
  }
```

I thinks, i put the JS counter inside

```
if (bottom_of_object < bottom_of_window){

        }
```

But it does not work. I want the counter start whan the window is center.

Comment: What does not work? Is there an error?

Comment: All doesn't work ! 
https://jsfiddle.net/cq0bf8hr/

I want when the 0 are verticaly center, the counter start